# AJAX for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I download the ajaxcontroltookit.binary4 file from codeplex is there an installer to install ajax 4 for Visual Studio 2010. Could someone give me some links to these things that I need, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the file to some location, say C:\Ajax
2. Open VS 2010
3. Open your toolbox (Go to view --> Toolbox if you can't see it)
4. Right click inside the toolbox, add new tab, say AJAX Controls toolkit
5. Open the new tab you created, right click inside it, click choose
   components
6. Click browse, and then select the .dll file from C:\Ajax

Comment: Is there any installer for ajax templates when you choose create new website

Comment: I mean a Web Template for VS 2010 that is ajax ready when you create a new website and also where do you get these file from are they part of the ajaxcontroltoolkit MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js
MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js I want to make sure I have all the library files needed

Comment: In VS 2008, whenever you create an ASP.NET page, it is already AJAX enabled.